# Download and Save Images Using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso, download

I'm trying to show my **news** in a custom **ListView**. Each **news** is included of some **images** and I want to

1.download **images** from server

2.save in local storage

3.save **path** of **images** into SQLite

4.show **images** in ListView using my custom adapter.

I just have problem with steps **1** & **2**. I can get **news** from server and show them in my **ListView**

and show **images** from cache by add below code in my adapter:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(image[position]).into(iv);
```

By using `Picasso.with(context).load(image[position]).into(target)` , just I can save one

**image** in storage.

Please suggest me your idea ...

**UPDATE**: When I use below code, just one image (last index of my image array) being saved!

How can I save all images in array with this code?!

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   SaveImages();
   pDialog.dismiss();
   super.onPostExecute(result);
}

String fileName = null;

public void SaveImages() {
    for(int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        Picasso.with(this).load(image[i]).into(target);
        fileName = "image-" + i + ".jpg";
    }
}

Target target = new Target() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/" + fileName);
         try {
             file.createNewFile();
             FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
             bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
             ostream.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
    }
};
```

Comment: you can use lazylist or universal image loader as alternative.

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27720638/1576416

Comment: @chet's, I've downloaded UIL Library, but I can't solve my problem with it, too !!! Could you please give me simple code ?

Comment: @AmrutBidri, I've checked your link. I can read images from url and put them into imageview directly. I just need download and save all images to local storage. I've searched internet and found out Picasso library is the best for this issue.

Comment: for what reason  you required image local storage path, Its mandatory? I am asking this bez i will provide soln accordingly.

Comment: @chet's, Because I want if users don't have access to the internet, they be able review news offline

Comment: Local storage can also be useful when the app in destroyed & created again, but this time without internet access.

Answer (score 7):

Try to put `Target target` definition before call to `Picasso.with(this).load(image[i]).into(target);`

P.S. Using the following code and I saved images very well. Thanks, anyway.

My Code:

```
        final String fileName = mDataset.get(i).getAid() + ".jpg";
        Target target = new Target() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
                return;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom arg1) {

                try {
                    File file = null;

                    // judge "imgs/.nomedia"'s existance to judge whether path available
                    if(LightCache.testFileExist(GlobalConfig.getFirstStoragePath()
                            + "imgs" + File.separator +".nomedia") == true)
                        file = new File(GlobalConfig.getFirstStoragePath()
                                + "imgs" + File.separator + fileName);

                    else file = new File(GlobalConfig.getSecondStoragePath()
                            + "imgs" + File.separator + fileName);

                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                    ostream.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
                return;
            }
        };

        Picasso.with(GlobalConfig.getContext())
                .load(Wenku8API.getCoverURL(mDataset.get(i).getAid()))
                .into(target);
```

Comment: This solution encodes the byte stream to a bitmap, then decodes re-compresses it to a file. Causes out of memory exceptions and loss of image quality.

Comment: LightCache and GlobalConfig not found.

Comment: @Programmingvirus Hi, the codes were just a sample. However, those missing classes are existing, **LightCache**: https://github.com/MewX/light-novel-library_Wenku8_Android/blob/master/studio-android/LightNovelLibrary/app/src/main/java/org/mewx/wenku8/util/LightCache.java ; and **GlobalConfig**: https://github.com/MewX/light-novel-library_Wenku8_Android/blob/master/studio-android/LightNovelLibrary/app/src/main/java/org/mewx/wenku8/global/GlobalConfig.java Hope this help!

Comment: with() isnt available anymore so this answer is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Custom target for storing photo in phone gallery.

```
public class TargetPhoneGallery implements Target
{
    private final WeakReference<ContentResolver> resolver;
    private final String name;
    private final String desc;

    public TargetPhoneGallery(ContentResolver r, String name, String desc)
    {
        this.resolver = new WeakReference<ContentResolver>(r);
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad (Drawable arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded (Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1)
    {
        ContentResolver r = resolver.get();
        if (r != null)
        {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(r, bitmap, name, desc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed (Drawable arg0)
    {
    }
}

Picasso.with(context).load(image[position]).into(new TargetPhoneGallery(view.getContentResolver(), "image name", "image desc"));
```

Answer (score 1):

although this post is old, it seems the question hasn't been answered yet.
Reading your code, it appears the call you make to picasso could be asynchronous.
You should definitely check that, as if it is the case, you are starting `image.length` tasks, changing the filename at each new task, leading all tasks to complete and save to the last filename that was set.
To solve this, you should override Target constructor and add a filename parameter so it's ready when the task ends, in your `onBitmapLoaded` listener.