# How to save the image contained in imageView to internal storage with Picasso

Tags: android, kotlin

Ok this I am running in a snippet

I have an imageView that gets its image randomly with picasso and I would like you to help me save that image to the internal storage of the device using a button

My code to generate the random image:

```java
private fun imageRandomFun() {
        val quest1 = "https://proxxcraft.com/"
        Picasso.get().load(quest1).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(memeRandomView)
        Picasso.get().isLoggingEnabled = true
    }
```

My layout:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/memeRandomView"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="452dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.578"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Next"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/memeRandomView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:text="Memes Random"
            android:textColor="#393636"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton.Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Descargar"
            app:icon="@drawable/download"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/memeRandomView" />
```

Comment: have you tried anything related to storing data? or you just gave a basic layout looking for someone who will write you full functionality. just ask any search engine, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729976/download-and-save-images-using-picasso) you have answer...

Comment: In fact, I do not let myself publish all the code and before publication I configure so that the application requests the necessary permissions to proceed to save the images but I don't know how to save an image generated with picasso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, since the image saving code too long, you can use this library to make thing easier for you `implementation 'com.blankj:utilcodex:1.30.0'`

Make sure the storage permission is granted :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

---

```
private fun downloadImage(){
    val quest1 = "https://proxxcraft.com/"
    Picasso.get().load(quest1).into(object : Target {
        override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap, from: LoadedFrom) {
            val file = ImageUtils.save2Album(bitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100)
            if (file!!.exists()) ToastUtils.showShort("Image Saved!")
        }
        override fun onBitmapFailed(e: Exception, errorDrawable: Drawable) {}
        override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable) {}
    })
}
```

When the image loaded, the `onBitmapLoaded` method return a `Bitmap` you can save it as file into your device storage

Comment: For whatever reason, the kotlin conversion of the code you provide me fails in, `Picasso.get().load(quest1).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into (object: Target()`since it does not detect the ImageView that has to go inside the into ()